# How to build a table with specific multicolumns?

Tags: tables, multicolumn, columns

Trying to format a table in the format of this poorly drawn Paint picture.[image]

I've seen similar examples posted of formatting tables like this, but I can't for the life of me get it to work as I want it. I've tried using `\multicolumn` but it just doesn't come out correctly... if someone can point out the similar question I've missed, or advise on how to do it I'd be really grateful.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Do the nine data columns have to have the same widths? Is automatic  line-breaking within a cell supposed to be enabled? Do you have to replicate the "prison cell window" look, or would you be ok giving your table a more open and inviting look? Please advise.

Comment: They don't need to be fixed length (though they can also be as they'll all have 6 characters in them...) And I'm definitely open to making it look less miserable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question unfortunately not provide enough information about desired table, so the following suggestion is based on guessing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand\mccc[1]{\multicolumn{3}{c|}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|*{9}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}}
    \hline
        &   \mccc{Rouge 1}  &   \mccc{Rouge 2}  &   \mccc{Rouge 2}  \\
        \cline{2-10}
        & F1 & P & R & F1 & P & R & F1 & P & R                      \\
    \hline
text    &    &   &   &    &   &   &    &   &                        \\
    \hline                          
        &    &   &   &    &   &   &    &   &                        \\     
    \hline
        &    &   &   &    &   &   &    &   &                        \\         
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to get to! Apologies for not providing enough info - rather new to this so must have missed something in the guidelines!

Comment: @user230843, you are welcome. Usually we expect that you show, what you try so far and where you stuck in your effort :-) BTW, that is one of many possible solutions ... More about tables is worth to read som introductory text about tables as is https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables